# Creating JSON object based on JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with retrieving information about movie when I send
`GET` request to omdbapi.com.

Here's the code that handles `POST` request to my database:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

const Movie = require('../models/movie');

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

    var temp;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            temp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + req.body.title + "&apikey=xyz", true);
    xhr.send();

    const movie = new Movie({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            title: req.body.title,
            movieInfo: temp,
            comment: req.body.comment
    });

    movie
    .save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Created movie succesfully',
            createdMovie: {
                _id: movie._id,
                title: movie.title,
                movieInfo: movie.movieInfo,
                comment: movie.comment
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error : err
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My problem here is, that everything gets passed except of movieInfo, which I want to be a nested JSON object, like

```
createdMovie{
 ...
 movieInfo: {
  Title: a,
  Actors: b,
  ...
  ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Here's a mongoose schema I work on

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    movieInfo: String,
    comment: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

When I `POST` a movie, that's what I get when testing (I use Postman for testing purposes).

```
{
    "message": "Created movie succesfully",
    "createdMovie": {
        "_id": "5b7b0da48f5fb04e3c0f740b",
        "title": "Goodfellas",
        "comment": "some comment"
    }
}
```

So I'm missing `movieInfo`, and I don't know if it's because it didn't even reach the object because I passed it in a wrong way, or it just doesn't get displayed. Tried with different mongoose types, like `String`, `Array`, `Mixed` and none worked.

JSON that you get, if request was successful, looks like that

```
{
    "Title":"Goodfellas",
    "Year":"1990",
    "Rated":"R",
    "Released":"21 Sep 1990",
    "Runtime":"146 min",
    "Genre":"Crime, Drama",
    "Director":"Martin Scorsese",
    "Writer":"Nicholas Pileggi (book), Nicholas Pileggi (screenplay), Martin Scorsese (screenplay)",
    "Actors":"Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci, Lorraine Bracco",
    "Plot":"The story of Henry Hill and his life in the mob, covering his relationship with his wife Karen Hill and his mob partners Jimmy Conway and Tommy DeVito in the Italian-American crime syndicate.","Language":"English, Italian","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 1 Oscar. Another 43 wins & 37 nominations.",
    "Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BY2NkZjEzMDgtN2RjYy00YzM1LWI4ZmQtMjIwYjFjNmI3ZGEwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.7/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"96%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"89/100"}],
    "Metascore":"89",
    "imdbRating":"8.7",
    "imdbVotes":"855,144",
    "imdbID":"tt0099685",
    "Type":"movie",
    "DVD":"26 Mar 1997",
    "BoxOffice":"N/A",
    "Production":"Warner Bros.",
    "Website":"N/A",
    "Response":"True"
}
```

And I would like to have it under `movieInfo`, the whole thing. How it can be accomplished?

Comment: at the time `movie` object is created you are setting `movieInfo` to `temp` which i don't see initialized. try initializing to a valid value and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

Everything has to be moved inside `xhr.onreadystatechange` because if not, then by the time I create a `Movie` object, the answer from omdbapi.com still didn't arrive.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    *your code here*
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the request sent with Content-Type - application/json ?

Answer (score 0):

Change movieInfo data type as Object.

```
const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    movieInfo: Object,
    comment: String
});
```

Comment: It is an object already, but I just tested it, and it seems that my code first creates a JSON object `movieInfo` with empty `temp`, then gets an answer from omdbapi.com and passes `JSON.parse(this.responseText)` to `temp`.
How can I make it wait for the response, pass it to `temp` and then create `movieInfo = temp`?

Comment: use asynchronous functions